# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'userRoleDOList')

Tags: angular, unit-testing, automated-tests, karma-jasmine, angular-test

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'userRoleDOList')
at AppLayoutComponent.getMenu (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/app/BaseFramework/base-ui/app-layout/app-layout.component.ts:405:52)
at AppLayoutComponent.ngOnInit (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/app/BaseFramework/base-ui/app-layout/app-layout.component.ts:381:12)
```

spec.ts file

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed, waitForAsync } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { AppMetadataHandler } from 'app/BaseFramework/configs';
import { ApiRequestService, AuthenticationService, CommonUtilty, UserInfoService } from 'app/BaseFramework/core';
import { MenuService } from 'app/BaseFramework/core/services/menu/menu.service';
import { MultiLingualService } from 'app/BaseFramework/core/services/multi-lingual/multi-lingual.service';
import { NgZorroAntdModule } from 'app/ng-zorro.module';

import { AppLayoutComponent } from './app-layout.component';

describe('AppLayoutComponent', () => {
  let component: AppLayoutComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppLayoutComponent>;
  let mockMultiLingualService;
  let mockAppMetadataHandler;
  let mockAuthenticationService;
  let mockMenuService;
  let mockUserInfoService;
  let mockCommonUtilty;
  let mockApiRequestService;
  beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
    mockMultiLingualService = jasmine.createSpyObj('MultiLingualService',['setLanguage']);
    mockAppMetadataHandler = jasmine.createSpyObj('AppMetadataHandler', ['getAppMetadata']);
    mockAuthenticationService = jasmine.createSpyObj('AuthenticationService', ['logout']);
    mockMenuService = jasmine.createSpyObj('MenuService', ['getMenu']);
    mockUserInfoService = jasmine.createSpyObj('UserInfoService', ['getUserInfo','setUserInfo']);
    // mockUserInfoService.getUserInfo.and.returnValue('userRoleDOList')
    mockCommonUtilty= jasmine.createSpyObj('CommonUtility', ['getAppMetadata','isArrayIterable']);
    mockApiRequestService = jasmine.createSpyObj('ApiRequestService', ['get']);
   
    
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ AppLayoutComponent ],
      providers: [
        {provide: MultiLingualService, useValue: mockMultiLingualService},
        {provide: AppMetadataHandler, useValue: mockAppMetadataHandler},
        {provide: AuthenticationService, useValue: mockAuthenticationService},
        {provide: MenuService, useValue: mockMenuService},
        {provide: UserInfoService, useValue: mockUserInfoService},
        {provide: CommonUtilty, useValue: mockCommonUtilty},
        {provide: ApiRequestService, useValue: mockApiRequestService},
      ],
      imports:[NgZorroAntdModule,RouterTestingModule]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppLayoutComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    component.getMenu()
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

.ts file

```
ngOnInit() {
if (environment['hardcodedMenu']) {
//this.getDemoMenu()
this.getDemoProposedMenu();
}
else {
this.getMenu();
}

    this.organizationMetaData = this.appOrganizationSettings.getOrganizationMetaData();
    
    this.featureFlagsArray = this.extractFeatureFlags(this.featureFlags);

}



getMenu() {
    let userInfo = this.userInfoService.getUserInfo();
    let userRole = null;
    if (this.commonUtilty.isArrayIterable(userInfo.userRoleDOList)) {
      let userRoleDO = userInfo.userRoleDOList.find(item => true);
      userRole = userRoleDO.roleId;
    }
```

is there any way to fake the getMenu method trying to read the userRoleDOList because I dont need the getMenu methods for my test as I am only testing an another function that is not inside the ngOnInIt.

Spec:

Angular CLI: 12.2.18

Node: 14.17.3

Package Manager: npm 6.14.13

OS: win32 x64

Angular: 12.2.17

Comment: You can add a flag as a parameter and set it when you run the tests and in the `getMenu(flag: boolean)` method you can make a if-statement about the new created flag and execut the method content or not

Comment: can we not make any changes on the spec file that could resolve the same? I do not want to edit the ts file

Comment: But what test are you testing? Unit-test?